# Show in real time the number of characters in a HTML textarea while the user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a blog comment `form` with a `textarea` and a `span` which shows to the user the number of remaining characters that can be introduced in the text area.

So I have this form:

```
<form action="comment.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="4" cols="56"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    <span id="comment-chars-left">512</span> characters left
</form>
```

And then I wrote the following jQuery code:

```
$('#comment')
    .keydown(function(event) {
        $('#comment-chars-left').html('' + (512 - $textarea.val().length));
    });
```

The problem is that when typing `.keydown` is called first, which prints the number of remaining characters and then the new character typed is shown in the `textarea`. So the number of remaining characters does not have a correct value, being bigger by one unit. To make this work `.keydown` should be called after the insertion of the new character.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Not actually answering your question, but watch out for new lines, which can be one character or two depending on the browser and how the new line was added.

Comment: You are right in UNIX-like operating systems a new line is `\n`, but in Windows it is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `keyup()` instead.

You will also want to bind a few other events.

Use `bind('keyup paste drop')`.

`keyup` for event when key is released, `paste` if someone pastes text in your `textarea`, and `drop` if someone drops a chunk of text in your `textarea`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mMgmb/).

Comment: `keyup()` works best for me, although is has a small problem: when holding a key for repeated characters the characters left label is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `$('#comment').keyup()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.keyup()` ?

```
$('#comment')
    .keyup(function(event) {
        $('#comment-chars-left').html('' + (512 - $textarea.val().length));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try the `.keyup` event instead

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keypress` event instead, which happens when a key produces a character, not when the key is pressed. (For example the shift key causes a `keydown` event but not a `keypress` event, and a key that repeats causes `keypress` events for each character, but only a `keydown` event at the first one.)

Use the `setTimeout` method to start a timer that will run the code after the event has been handled:

```
$('#comment')
  .keypress(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('#comment-chars-left').html('' + (512 - $textarea.val().length));
    }, 0);
  });
```

Comment: Why the `setTimeout()`? Thanks.

Comment: @alex: So that the code runs after the event has been handled, i.e. after the character has been added to the textarea.