# JQuery function for showing remaining characters in textarea/input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a piece of JQuery to show the number of remaining characters when typing into a textarea/input field. But it doesn't seem to be working, I'm very new to JQuery so I'm sure its something simple below is a copy of the code:

```
$(":textarea[data-limit-input]").keyup(function () {
var charLength = $(this).val().length;
var charLimit = $(this).attr("data-val-length-max");
// Displays count
$(this).next("span").html(charLength + " of " + charLimit + " characters used");
// Alert when max is reached
if ($(this).val().length > charLimit)
    $(this).next("span").html("<strong>You may only have up to " + charLimit + " characters.   </strong>");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: looks right to me, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Remove : in front of textarea and close the function and the if statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673667/show-in-real-time-the-number-of-characters-in-a-html-textarea-while-the-user-typ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Zvhq/

I changed the textarea selector, added the right data-value to charLimit and closed the funktion and the if statement.

EDIT
I updated it so it will return false if you're trying to type when the limit is reached and made it prettier :)

http://jsfiddle.net/7Zvhq/3/

Comment: The only change I would make to this answer is changing `$this.val().length > charLimit` to `$this.val().length >= charLimit`.  Otherwise, the user is actually allowed to enter `charLimit + 1` characters in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing the }); at the end? Also the :textarea can be written as $("textarea[data-limit-input]") since this is a normal CSS selector.

Otherwise I can't see anything strange.

Answer (score 0):

set attr maxlength for textarea: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp
each keyup check count maxlength - textarea.val().length

Answer (score 0):

Is data-limit-input the id or name of your textarea?

I'd try

```
$('textarea#data-limit-input').keyup(handler);
```

or

```
$('textarea[name="data-limit-input"]').keyup(handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code in textarea for remaining character input.

The code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var totalChars      = 200; 
    var countTextBox    = jQuery('#comment')
    var charsCountEl    = jQuery('#countchars');

    charsCountEl.text(totalChars);
    countTextBox.keyup(function() { 
        var thisChars = this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length; 
        if(thisChars > totalChars) 
        {
            var CharsToDel = (thisChars-totalChars);
            this.value = this.value.substring(0,this.value.length-CharsToDel);
        }else{
            charsCountEl.text( totalChars - thisChars );
        }
    });
});
```

You can also see demo here.
http://jsfiddle.net/kishan_web/1k49s5vr/